# Azure DevOps automatically merge main (master) to the build branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps yml pipeline in which it is configured that after successful passing of the tests I can merge the code into the main (master). But since we have a large team the main (master) branch can go far from the development branches. How can I add (marge) the current main (master) branch to the development branch at the start of the build. Thanks.

Comment: If I'm tracking your question, neither of the responses address it. You want for outstanding PRs to be auto merged from main whenever a commit happens on main, yes?

Answer (score 0):

In your feature branch run `git merge master`.

This will merge master into your feature branch.

If it merges successfully, you can do `git add -A; git commit -m "back merged master" and push the changes to your feature branch or handle in whatever way you see fit.

But, the key point is that if it cannot merge due to merge conflicts it will tell you. You can then fail the job and have the devs do the same in dev, resolve any merge conflicts and then restart the job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe there is some kind of extension in Azure DevOps?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I use Jenkins for my pipeline work and the setup I mentioned up there is what I use. There might be a plugin for Azure to do just that but in my opinion that should be done via shell scripting in your pipeline.

Comment: Perhaps you have a ready-made script for merge changes in master to my branches in Azure DevOps

Answer (score 0):

The Azure DevOps has a concept of merge types designed just for the purpose of enforcing the merge strategy. It doesn't matter how far behind your source branch is compared to the target branch, Azure DevOps will try to merge it on the pull request completion applying [the merge type you choose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#complete-the-pull-request).

Here is [a great article describing the differences of the merge types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/pull-requests-with-rebase/), and  it becomes the matter of taste or an agreement inside the team which strategy to proceed with.

Of course, if you have merge conflicts, you'll have to resolve those before the merging can happen. That is true for any system, not only Azure DevOps.